# running php script on windows via bat file returns error on require_once ($_SERVER['Document_Root']);

Tags: php, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

On Windows XP system, I have **test.bat**

```
C:\Path\to\php.exe -f "C:\Path\to\test.php"
```

I also have **test.php**

```
require_once ($_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Inc/Class/Connect_DB.php');
```

... more code.

When I execute **test.bat** on "CMD mode" it returns Fatal error saying it can't locate the require_once file.

The same file works fine on the browser. It seems that it can't recognize `$_SERVER` variable on the bat file. (I plan to run **test.bat** file via schtasks.exe later on)

Why can't it read `$_SERVER` variable here?

Comment: If you're running PHP in a batch file, not serving web pages, but **as a command-line thing**, what does `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROO']` mean? Where's the server it refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump $_SERVER and check if document root is set. On my install $_SERVER is available  from cli, but the DOCUMENT_ROOT key is set to an empty string. ie -> "".

You would be better off getting the path  by using something in the lines of:

```
<?php echo dirname(__FILE__);?>
  //you can put this in variable, 
   $base_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
   //append another path ..
   $lib_dir = $base_dir . "/lib/";
   // Notice require does not need parentheses! ;)
   require_once $lib_dir . "db_connect.php";
```

There are many ways of doing this, but that should give you an idea.

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks, but how can I define absolute path of the document root?

Comment: You don't need $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for this, you can put it in a variable somewhere: ie: $base_root = "/path/to/my/document_root/"; or use the code I gave you up above. Look up dirname()  and __FILE__ on php.net and see what it does, they are quite handy to know. If you need help just message me back.

Comment: Since I used too many $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in files and many includes, I just overwrote to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as "C:Xampp/to/app/". (and sometimes I excute the file on the browser for testing purposes. So I really wanted to use the varialbe as it was.) But, thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

documentroot is empty when called from CLI

USE "__DIR__" : http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: __DIR__ is avaible from php 5.3 only